# Ubuntu can`t boot after update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, mount

I just updated my ubuntu via `do-release-upgrade -c` from 18.04 to the 20.02 version. I rebotoed 1 or 2 without problems. Now when I turn on my computer I get the message

/tmp/mountroot-fail-hooks.d/scripts/init-premount/lvm2 no such file or directory
/dev/sda4 clean xxxx files yyyy blocks

how can I fix that? I have a bootable usb and tried to check and fix the partition with gparted, no success. I tried running boot-repair and got errors  (paste.ubuntu.com/p/FY87GWTXKz)

gparted says that partion is not mounted (see image)

I tried mounting the partition with disks

```
cat /etc/fstab
overlay / overlay rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0
/dev/sda4 /mnt/sda4 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

nothing worked. Please some help!

I have dual boot with windows 10

[image]

Comment: Same problem. This seems sorta common, searching "mountroot fail"... And the solution seems to be involving  fstab, whatever that means...